# Cannot print proper pascal triangle in scala

Tags: scala

All the code I have seen related to Pascal Triangle are printing right angle triangles. How do I print a triangle like

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

Samples of similar code I have seen

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = c match {
   case 0 => 1
   case `c` if c >= r => 1
   case _ => pascal(c-1, r-1)+pascal(c,r-1)          
}
for (row <- 0 to 5) {
   for (col <- 0 until row)
       print(pascal(col, row)+ " ")
     println()
}
```

Comment: You can start by converting the C code examples [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/pyramid-pattern#pyramid). It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: You can insert `print(" "*(5-row))` before the 2nd `for`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a set of lines and use the longest to calculate the offset of the other lines.

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = c match {
  case 0 => 1
  case `c` if c >= r => 1
  case _ => pascal(c-1, r-1)+pascal(c,r-1)
}

val lines =
  (0 to 5)
    .map(row => (0 to row).map(col => pascal(col, row)))
    .map(_.mkString(" "))

val maxLength = lines.map(_.length).max

lines.foreach { line =>
  val len = line.length
  val numpad = (maxLength - len) / 2 + 1

  val padding = (1 to numpad).foldLeft("")((acc, _) => acc ++ " ")
  println("|" ++ padding ++ line ++ padding ++ "|")
}
```

Prints:

```
|       1       |
|      1 1      |
|     1 2 1     |
|    1 3 3 1    |
|   1 4 6 4 1   |
| 1 5 10 10 5 1 |
```

For some reason (at least on my worksheet) it won't print the spaces unless there is something in front of them.  Weird?!?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to try and balance the triangle as the numbers grow to 3, 4, and 5 digits in length.

```
def pascalTriangle(height :Int) :Unit = 
  Stream.iterate(Vector(1))(v => (0+:v:+0).sliding(2).map(_.sum).toVector)
        .take(height)
        .map(_.mkString(" "))
        .scanRight(("",0)){ case (line,(prev,padLen)) =>
          (line, if (prev=="") 0 else (prev.length - line.length)/2 + padLen)
        }.map{case (str,pad) => "." + " "*pad + str}
        .foreach(println)
```

usage:

```
pascalTriangle(17)
.                                 1
.                                1 1
.                               1 2 1
.                              1 3 3 1
.                             1 4 6 4 1
.                           1 5 10 10 5 1
.                          1 6 15 20 15 6 1
.                         1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
.                        1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
.                      1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
.                  1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
.                1 11 55 165 330 462 462 330 165 55 11 1
.              1 12 66 220 495 792 924 792 495 220 66 12 1
.          1 13 78 286 715 1287 1716 1716 1287 715 286 78 13 1
.       1 14 91 364 1001 2002 3003 3432 3003 2002 1001 364 91 14 1
.    1 15 105 455 1365 3003 5005 6435 6435 5005 3003 1365 455 105 15 1
.1 16 120 560 1820 4368 8008 11440 12870 11440 8008 4368 1820 560 120 16 1
.
```

The leading dot `.` is for displays that collapse leading spaces.

Comment: This actually does not really print a triangle once it reaches a certain number. I found a solution written by rwilson which works - https://gist.github.com/rwilson/722438